# Asp.Net MVC: @Html.ValidationMessage not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Below code is not working:

```
@Html.TextBox("List[" + i + "].prop", Model[i].prop)
@Html.ValidationMessage("List[" + i + "].prop")
```

I cannot use `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` because my model is a complex type with child collections
Note: @Html.ValidationMessageFor works for parent properties, so there is no problem of client scripts.

Any help would be great.

Comment: What is it validating for? You'll need to add more context. End of day, they'll all be key/value pairs (standard `form` payload)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution by using `@Html.TextBoxFor` and setting the Name property manually.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].prop, new { Name = "List[" + i + "].prop"})
@Html.ValidationMessage("List[" + i + "].prop")
```

Yet I haven't been able to find the reason why '@Html.TextBox' is not working.

Thanks.